# Boostrap select icon spacace

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello using this code my icon on the left has an space from field, and i need to eliminate this space, any idea how do this, thanks

```html
 <div class="col-auto">
   <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Full Name</label>
   <div class="input-group mb-2">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i></div>
  </div>
  <select class="selectpicker show-tick col-3" id="inputGroupSelect03"  name="name" data-live-search="true" required>
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select Contact Name</option>
   
</select>

  </div>
```

Comment: Not sure what space you mean can you elaborate? Also `fas fa-user-tie` should be `fa fa-user-tie`

Comment: @Clint in the latest version of `fontawesome` theres a `solid` version so you need to write `fas` instead fo `fa`

Comment: @Chirist2000 could you provide us with a screenshot for your result?

Comment: hello see the image <a href="https://imgbb.com/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/GnnMfv8/Screen-Shot-10-02-19-at-11-13-AM.png" alt="Screen-Shot-10-02-19-at-11-13-AM" border="0" /></a>

Comment: https://ibb.co/HBBPLDb

Comment: The image link is : https://ibb.co/HBBPLDb

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? I tested your code and get no space. https://ibb.co/Tv6bfP4

Comment: the last one, but i am using https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#styling

Comment: the reason is this mod allow search in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

If you add the class `pl-0` to the `select` element, the space (padding) will be removed.

```
    <div class="col-auto mt-3">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Full Name</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i></div>
            </div>
            <select class="selectpicker show-tick col-3 pl-0" id="inputGroupSelect03"  name="name" data-live-search="true" required>
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Contact Name</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In my opinion that will not look 'nice' as the select box has rounded corners with the select plugin you are using. That really negates the use of an input-group from pure bootstrap. Perhaps there is an option from the plugin which removes the rounded corners on the left.

Comment: hello using pl-0 overlap field in icon, check image https://ibb.co/JjFDBp7

Comment: @Christ2000 Replace the following: 

```<div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i></div>```

with

```<div class="input-group-text" style="z-index:10;"><i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i></div>```

Let me know if that works for you

Comment: dont work, but i fix using like this <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="typeposition" required>